# How do to repeatedly move an elemtent in Vue?

Tags: jquery, css, vue.js

Using jQuery to repeatedly move an element right is easy, every time I want to do it I can just call this:

```
$('#element').css({left: '+=100'});
```

or alternatively

```
$('#element').animate({
   left: '+=100'
}, 500);
```

How would I do something similar in Vue, preferably with the value being a variable and also being animated?

Comment: Did my answer helped anyhow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working solution on how to achieve the translation and transition: https://codesandbox.io/s/move-element-and-animation-7v2do?file=/src/App.vue

---

The transition is done purely in CSS

```css
transition: transform 500ms ease;
```

The `move` logic is as simple as it gets. Could maybe make something more dynamic with `getBoundingClientRect()` but this example can be improved in many ways depending on what you're aiming for.

```js
data() {
  return {
    horizontalOffset: 0,
    verticalOffset: 0,
  }
},
methods: {
  move(x = 0, y = 0) { // defaults to 0 if no arguments passed to `move`
    this.horizontalOffset += x * 10
    this.verticalOffset += y * 10
    // we do select the element with `$refs`, then translate it accordingly to our `data`
    this.$refs.element.style.transform = `translate(${this.horizontalOffset}px, ${this.verticalOffset}px)`
  },
  reset() {
    this.horizontalOffset = 0
    this.verticalOffset = 0
    this.move()
  },
},
```

And lastly, we do need some basic markup to which we may give some variables as argument

```html
<button @click="move(-10, 0)">move to left</button>
```